# How do I "send" data to a message box?

Tags: c#, winforms, udp, chat

I'm building a UDP chat in C#, and when one of the users chooses to disconnect, I want to send the other user a message box which says that the other user has left the chat. How can it be done?

Comment: send a messagebox?  I assume you'll send a message that means disconnect... then showa messagebox...

Comment: You don't "send" UI elements.  You send data.  The applications would present that data using UI elements.  How are you currently sending data from one instance to another in this case?

Comment: If you're asking how to display a message box, the syntax is `MsgBox.Show("message");`. As David says, communicating from one instance to another depends entirely on how you designed the software. You'll need to provide more information in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Don't send chat text as plain text via UDP. Make some packet types for your application. For example put "TEXT" before chat messages. If user sends "hello", you should send "TEXThello" in UDP. When you receive this packet, you should check first 4 bytes. If it's "TEXT", so it is text message. And add "DSCN" message which you should send it when user wants to exit. When you receive a UDP packet which it's first 4 byte is "DSCN", it means that user disconnected.